# Filling an HTML table sorted vertically from an array in C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sorting, html-table

This has been hurting my brain for the past couple of days and I'm rather new to C#.  It's proven to be quite a challenge.

The end result I need is populating an HTML table sorted vertically for any given number of columns and number of values in a 2D array (array is already in order).
Such as:

```
|01|07|13|19|25|31|37|43|
|02|08|14|20|26|32|38|44|
|03|09|15|21|27|33|39|  |
|04|10|16|22|28|34|40|  |
|05|11|17|23|29|33|41|  |
|06|12|18|24|30|36|42|  |
```

With empty spaces only in the final column.

I just deleted my post because I had an afterthought that it would also be acceptable if it were like:

```
|01|07|13|19|25|30|35|40|
|02|08|14|20|26|31|36|41|
|03|09|15|21|27|32|37|42|
|04|10|16|22|28|33|38|43|
|05|11|17|23|29|34|39|44|
|06|12|18|24|  |  |  |  |
```

With empty cells only on the final row. (However, my code is currently going for the previous example... which may be the problem.)

My code is as follows:

```
int columnCount = 8;
int index = 0;
int tdcount = 0;
int trcount = 1;
String arrayhtml2 = "<table><tr>";
int numStatuses = Enumerable.Range(0, statuses.GetLength(0)).Count(i => statuses[i, 0] != null); //counts not null rows in array

//numStatuses = 28; //14, 21, multiples of 7 are all weird, and 18

double rowCount = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(numStatuses) / Convert.ToDouble(columnCount)); //gets total number of rows including blanks
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount * columnCount; i++)
{
    index = Convert.ToInt32((i % columnCount) * rowCount + Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(i) / (columnCount))); //determines index number to print to that cell
    if (index < numStatuses) //determines if a row should be populated or blank
    {
        arrayhtml2 += "<td>" + statuses[index, 0] + "</td>";
    }
    else
    {
        //blank
        arrayhtml2 += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }

    tdcount++; //counts to figure out when to make new row
    if (tdcount >= columnCount && trcount != rowCount)
    {
        trcount++;
        arrayhtml2 += "</tr><tr>";
        tdcount = 0;
    }
}
arrayhtml2 += "</tr></table>";
statusbox.Text = arrayhtml2;
```

Basically it works, however when you set numStatuses (where I have it commented out) to a multiple of 7 (this ends up leaving last column blank) or 18 (this ends up doing 6 columns  with 3 rows), it acts weird.

Also, I left out some code to make it easier to look at. I am using a 2D array to determine what color to set as the background of the cell.

I apologize if the code is ugly... I'm not the best programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  This is the gist for future generations.

```
        int numStatuses = Enumerable.Range(0, statuses.GetLength(0)).Count(i => statuses[i, 0] != null); //counts not null rows in array
        int numColumns = 9;
        int remainder = numStatuses % numColumns;
        int floorRows = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(numStatuses) / Convert.ToDecimal(numColumns)));
        int ceilingRows = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(numStatuses) / Convert.ToDecimal(numColumns)));
        int numRows = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(numStatuses) / Convert.ToDouble(numColumns)));
        int colCount = 0;
        int index = 0;
        double colWidth = Math.Round((100.00 / numColumns), 2);
        String statusHTML = null;

            statusHTML = "<table width=\"100%\">\n<tr>\n<td width=\"" + colWidth + "%\">";
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) // runs for the total number of columns
            {
                if (index < numStatuses) // doesn't print blank array values
                {
                    if (colCount < remainder) // columns that go down all the way
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < ceilingRows; j++)
                        {
                            statusHTML += "<div class=\"" + statuses[index, 1] + "\">" + statuses[index, 0] + "</div>";
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    else // columns that don't go down all the way
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < floorRows; j++)
                        {
                            statusHTML += "<div class=\"" + statuses[index, 1] + "\">" + statuses[index, 0] + "</div>";
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    colCount++;
                    if (colCount < numColumns && colCount < numStatuses) // checks if done with column
                    {
                        statusHTML += "</td><td width=\"" + colWidth + "%\">";
                    }
                    else if (colCount == numColumns)
                    {
                        colCount = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (numStatuses < numColumns) // if it's only one row
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numColumns - numStatuses; j++)
                {
                    statusHTML += "</td>\n<td width=\"" + colWidth + "%\">";
                }
            }
            statusHTML += "</td>\n</tr>\n</table>";
        }
```

Edit: Note: I'm actually tricking it to look like a table but I'm actually loading a table with div elements so I can load one column at a time without having to skip indexes.  The div's are set as block elements with a bottom border and float left.  They end up looking like table cells. It's kind of shisty but it works and gets the needed end result.